# Is there an alternate solution to this problem in C?

Tags: c++, c

I'm using this website called MyProgrammingLab, which coincides with a book teaching me how to program in C.   Many times the book does not prepare you well enough for the questions on MPL, but this one instance is probably the worst example of this problem.   The question is this, revolving around recursive functions.

"Write a recursive, int-valued function, len, that accepts a string and returns the number of characters in the string.

The length of a string is:

0 if the string is the empty string ("").
1 more than the length of the rest of the string beyond the first character."

I couldn't figure it out myself so I looked online for some help, and found this solution on a C++ forum (NOT C, which is the language I should be using), and it worked.

```
int len(string s){
  if (s.length()==0){
    return 0;
  }else{
    return 1+(len(s.erase(0,1)));
  }
}
```

Normally, when I've attempted to use syntax from C++, MPL says that it's a C course, not C++, and that I'm incorrect, yet this time it had no issues.   Why?  Is there a solution to this problem in C and why does this supposed C++ solution work instead?

Comment: It is very simple. `len(s) = 1 + len(s+1)` for non-empty `s`. Or `0` for empty (note that `s+1` is a pointer arithmetic).

Comment: You can do something similar in C (e.g. `s.length()`) but it would involve function pointers.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem.  I have scanned the chapter (and all prior chapters) thoroughly, nothing related to len(s) is present.

Comment: `string` isn't even defined in plain C (and, stylistically, many would have an issue with the implied `using namespace std;` in C++); that is definitely not valid C. @EugeneSh. have given you what you need for the correct answer — the exercise seems just to need you to understand: (i) what a string is in C; (ii) pointer arithmetic; and (iii) how to express yourself recursively.

Comment: I'm beginning to think this MPL garbage is trash.   It's given me errors for correct code, it frequently and consistently pulls stuff from either chapters we haven't covered, or from even outside of the book.

Comment: Tommy, pointers aren't even mentioned for another two chapters ahead lmao

Comment: Please use specific titles that others are likely to search for. "Is there an alternate solution to this problem in C?" says nothing about the problem. Recursion for finding a string's length is an abuse of recursion and makes me think your learning resource is questionable. Use a loop to avoid call overhead and blowing the stack. If the goal is to teach recursion, I'd use a tree problem, binary search or divide and conquer that reduces the problem space by a sublinear factor.

Comment: If MyProgrammingLab accepted that code, then either you were in a C++ mode or it is bad and accepted C++ code where C code was expected. The fact it previously detected that some code was C++ and not C does not mean it is able to detect all code that is C++ and not C.

Answer (score 1):

As [Eugene Sh.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66391746/is-there-an-alternate-solution-to-this-problem-in-c#comment117373899_66391746) said, it's very simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int len (const char* s){
    if (*s) return 1 + len(s+1);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    const char* string = "foobar";
    printf("The length of %s is %d.\n", string, len(string));
    return 0;
}
```

[link for testing](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/1sWTWUM)

Comment: Man I still have to have a chat with my instructor.   Len is not mentioned once in the textbook.

Comment: @BobHupcher It is *you* who is implementing `len()` here. Why would it be mentioned?

Comment: How is `len` not mentioned? The problem statement you quote in your question says “Write a recursive, int-valued function, **len**, that accepts a string and returns the number of characters in the string.”

Comment: That solution didn't work anyway.   It gave me an error message saying "You almost certainly should be using "==" "." and "string".

Comment: "Didn't work" and "wasn't accepted" are two very different concepts.

Comment: This answer is a perfectly valid and working C code. The issue is with your checker which has its own prejudices of how the solution should look like.

Comment: @Bob something weird is going on. Based on the feedback you got and the acceptance of C++ code, the marking bot is expecting C++ code. Sounds like the marking bot is, for this assignment anyway, <expletive deleted>ed.

Comment: The answer literally provides a link that demonstrate that the code compiles and performs the task. So, it works. That much should have been obvious. The site you're submitting to is opinionated on what the solution should look like, and did not accept a working solution. My statement about "didn't work" and "wasn't accepted" is not a novel programming thing. It's life.

Comment: @BobHupcher, according to TIOBE, C is the most popular programming language of 2021, see https://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/

Comment: But it's not object-oriented, nor does it receive frequent updates, I don't see that lasting for long.

Comment: C ain't going anywhere. It's too low level for most programming work, but it's too important in the really low level programming to discard. As for the output being more important than the path to the output, you're about 80% correct. Source code is supposed to describe program behaviour that a compiler transforms into machine-runnable instructions that implement the described behaviour, but there are better ways to describe the behaviour so that potential misbehaviour is eliminated and easier to find and fix if it can't be eliminated.

Comment: That said, no one sane is going to use recursion to find the length of a string. That way lies madness. The assignment may turn out to be educational, but is practically flawed.